# Focus on a div parent even when focusing on a child and then blur if not

Tags: javascript, html, angular

> **PREFACE:** I want to focus the wrapper, then the additional element below the textarea shows, and I want to click inside it without the `blur` event interfering (in case that I attach it to the textarea, which works, but I can't use the element below).

I have the following structure:

```
<div (focus)="onInputFocus()" (blur)="onInputBlur()">
    <textarea></textarea>
    // Some additional element here
</div>
```

I want to enable `focus` for the div element, but I do not know how. I have tried using [**tabindex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) , but without any luck, like this:

```
<div tabindex=1 ... >
```

Usually the focus was meant for the textarea, but I need some additional content with it in a wrapper, which needs a `focus` event.

Comment: `Usually the focus was meant for the textarea, but I need some additional content with it in a wrapper, which needs a focus event.` -- With this rationale, I find it no harm in retaining the focus and blur listeners on the textarea.

Comment: @AbanaClara , yes , but when you click inside that element, which I need to do - the `blur` event comes into action, therefore removing itself.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Have you tried attaching all focus and blur events on all the children instead? Then on those event callbacks, assign a flag to prevent double execution.

Comment: @AbanaClara , yes , this is basically the same issue , just one more layer deep. The second child is also a div, therefore the problem remains the same.

Comment: This sounds like a huge stretch trying to make it work with native focus and blur events. Because even if you make focus and blur work on the parent div, any focus on the children will execute the blur event for the parent div. And any focus on any sibling of this child will execute the blur for the previous child. What are you doing on `onInputFocus` and `onInputBlur`?